# How to apply data-target attribute from select option to a button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I grab the data-target attribute from the options and apply that data-target as a data-target to the button after the selection is made?

HTML:

```
<div>
<select id="selectID">
                <option value="option1" data-target="data1">Select</option>
                <option value="option1" data-target="data1">Select</option>
            </select>
            <button id="selBtn" data-target="">Button</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $("#selectID").change(function () {
                            var prop = $(this).data("data-target");
                            $("#selBtn").attr("data-target", prop);
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace second line with `var prop = $("#selectID option:selected").data("target");`.

**SIDE NOTE:** It's a good practice to have a default option with value 0 (or default). So the option1 is not selected automatically.

```js
$("#selectID").change(function () {
  var prop = $("#selectID option:selected").data("target");
  $("#selBtn").attr("data-target", prop);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<select id="selectID">
    <option value="0" data-target="data1">Please Select</option>
    <option value="option1" data-target="data1">Select 1</option>
    <option value="option2" data-target="data2">Select 2</option>
</select>
<button id="selBtn" data-target="">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).data("data-target")`

With `this` you are selecting #selectID reference.

Try this:

```
 $("#selectID").change(function() {
  console.log($(this).find(':selected').data('target'));

});
```